# Fluent NHibernate with Key/Value Column Relation

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to create a table that will work as additional data for another table.

- For example I have my main table called **Person**. This table will contain zero or many dynamic records (Free text key and free text value) from a table called **PersonDynamicInfo**.

  public PersonMap(){ 
    Id(x => x.Id);
    Table("Person");
    Map(x => x.Name);

  HasMany(x => x.PersonDynamicInfo)
      .KeyColumn("Id")
      .Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore)
      .AsSet()
      .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
      .Not.KeyNullable();
  }

  public PersonDynamicInfo(){ 
    Id(x => x.Id);
    Table("PersonDynamicInfo");
    Map(x => x.Key);
    Map(x => x.Value);
  }

What I want to achieve is the following:

- When I access the **Person** object, I want to be able to edit Person.PersonDynamicInfo so that the information on this table is the same as the object. Let's say for example that I create a person with a record on PersonDynamicInfo with the values: "***Key:*** A | **Value**: TEST". When I access the Person object I will remove all the Person.PersonDynamicInfo (from the collection) and add a new one: "***Key:*** B | **Value**: TEST" and Save() this Person object.
  What will happen is that the Person.PersonDynamicInfo will contain the two records instead of only containing the last one.

Is there way I can achieve this without manually deleting the unused records on PersonDynamicInfo?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a reference to the `Person` in your `PersonDynamicInfo` mapping:

```
public PersonDynamicInfo(){ 
    Id(x => x.Id); 
    Table("PersonDynamicInfo"); 
    Map(x => x.Key);
    Map(x => x.Value);
    References(x => x.Person, "PersonId").Cascade.All(); 
}
```

I may have misunderstood your question, however.